# "Contradiction" tag -- second passing

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-blacklist

The [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) tag has been discussed previously, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20180/43351). It was also mentioned [in the tag management thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20197/43351).

On both accounts, it was reasonably favoured that something ought to be done about it. Looking at the questions, the only constant among them is the occurrence of the word "contradiction" or one of its derivatives in the post. That makes the tag useless for both favouriting and ignoring. And indeed, it currently does have the grand total of zero followers.

The prolonged existence of this tag is increasingly bugging me. The continued unclarity about the scope of the tag (as exemplified in the other thread) and its very ad-hoc use make it a perfect candidate for burnination.

Bring [Trogdor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121570/222340), I say!

---

*Update*: Given the vote tally, it's time to put things ablaze. (*Insert maniacal laughing as deemed appropriate.*)

---

<s>NB. There are some questions remaining carrying only the [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) tag; these will have to be attended to.</s> All such questions have been attended to.

Comment: Trogdor... he burninates!

Comment: +1 for calling Trogdor. How could this tag survive for so long anyway?

Comment: @Alex: Easily. We prove a theorem: The [contradiction] tag should be burninated. *Proof.* Assume towards contradiction that it shouldn't be burninated...

Comment: [There are only 9 questions with contradiction as the only tag.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcontradiction%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: @Najib All gone now.

Comment: ... contradiction! $\square$ (Thus the proof from the previous comment is concluded.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And, lo, the [contadiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contadiction) tag did battle with the mighty Trogdor, but it was a foregone conclusion. Though the humble tag did parry and thrust with all its might, the armor-like scales resisted all attacks. The dragon<s>-man</s> picked up the tag with its arm, and with a single great breath of flame the tag ceased to be. Not even ashes remained.

A great hush swept across the land, everyone having the same singular thought: Trogdor! Burninating the countryside! Burninating the tags!

[image: Burninated]

Comment: Users can blame/congratulate Tim Post for unleashing this beast.